# how to customize x-axis in matplotlib when plotting

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization, data-analysis

I have a bar chart, the x-axis is (1,2,3...12).
so my bar chart is something like this:
[image]

how can I change:

```
1---> -6month 
2---> -1 year
3--->-1.5 year
.
.
.
```

while showing?

my code to plot is:

```
dffinal = df[['6month','final-formula','Question Text','numPatients6month']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['6month'])

df = dffinal.drop('numPatients6month', 1).groupby(['6month','Question Text']).sum().unstack('Question Text')

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
ax=df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.xticks(fontsize=8, rotation=45)
#ax2.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.0))
dffinal.plot(ax=ax2,x='6month', y='numPatients6month',visible=False)
plt.title('Cognitive Impairement-Stack bar')
plt.show()
```

I have two df as I have two y-axis.

I tried to use replace:

```
   dffinal['6month'].replace(1, '-6 month',inplace=True)
dffinal['6month'].replace(2, '-1 year',inplace=True)
```

but it just did not worked .

Thanks:)

Comment: Sorry but there's very little in common between your code and the plot you show :-) do you mean to just change the x ticks showing some text instead of 1,..., 12? If so, you just need to write a command like `plt.xticks(range(1,13), ['-6month','-1 year',...], fontsize=8, rotation=90)` instead of the `plt.xticks` you currently have. Your question title says y axis, but the y axis in this case doesn't make much sense with text / categorical variables...

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci thanks for your response I just edited the title. my mind was full withthe previous problem I had thats why you see some conflicts. I did not know I can add it in x.ticks now I am trying your code, then I will update

Comment: and about the conflict between plot and code you are right, I plotted one example I had and did not want run the code that has problem

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci it works perfectly, except it should be range(0,12) . please add your answer so I can choose it as the desired one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `plt.xticks` should take care of it. Depending on whether the counting of the x axis starts from 0 (as default) or from 1 (as your plot implies) you could try:

```
# If x starts from 0
plt.xticks(range(12), ['-6month','-1 year',...], fontsize=8, rotation=90)
```

or

```
# If x starts from 1
plt.xticks(range(1,13), ['-6month','-1 year',...], fontsize=8, rotation=90)
```

In both cases replacing `['-6month','-1 year',...]` by the 12 elements list of the labels you want.